# Как изменить цвет текста в QLabel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, qlabel

Есть `QLabel`, как изменить цвет текста в `RGB`?

```
self.Label = QtWidgets.QLabel("", self)
self.Label.move(50, 30)
self.Label.resize(421, 41)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> QLabel Class
>
> Виджет QLabel обеспечивает отображение текста или изображения.
>
> При передаче QString в конструктор или вызове setText (), убедитесь, что санировали ваш ввод, так как QLabel пытается угадать, отображает ли он текст в виде простого текста или как форматированный текст, подмножество разметки **HTML 4**. Вы можете явно вызывать setTextFormat (), например, в случае, если вы ожидаете, что текст будет в простом формате, но не можете управлять источником текста (например, при отображении данных, загруженных из Интернета).

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *
        
        
class Demo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.label = QLabel('Есть <h1 style="color: rgb(250, 55, 55);">QLabel,</h1>как изменить цвет текста в RGB?', 
                             self, 
                             alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setFont(QFont("Times", 12, QFont.Bold))
        
        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = QApplication(sys.argv)
    open = Demo()
    open.show()
    sys.exit(root.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]